# Finally block to behave differently

Tags: java, try-catch, try-catch-finally, finally

I have a condition like this

```
String str = null;

try{
  ...
  str = "condition2";
}catch (ApplicationException ae) {
  str = "condition3";
}catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
  str = "condition3";
}catch (Exception e) {
  str = "condition3";
}

if(str == null){
  str = "none";
}
```

Now I want to sum up all `str = "condition3";` in one line. As finally block runs always so that will not fulfill my needs. What else can be done.

Comment: what do you mean by "sum up"?

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit you're looking for...  if you want the error string to be the same for all 3 exceptions, then use the below answers.  If not, and there's more code in each of the exception blocks we're not seeing, then I don't see that repeating one line is all that bad.

Comment: what does it mean "all str="condition3"? if you want to sum up all str, it will be consist from cond2 and one from three exceptions.

Comment: @ Bill James: After all this. Only "I don't see that repeating one line is all that bad" idea will work for me.

Comment: Dont you think that there should be a block like catchFinally....

Comment: Suppose you have a `catchFinally`, show us how it would work.

Comment: I suggest that this 'requirement' is evidence of a much bigger problem. More probably you should be letting the exception propogate, rather than assigning special values based on whether or not you got an exception. And how exactly is `str` ever going to be null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beginning in Java 7, you can [catch multiple exception types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) in a single `catch` block. The code looks something like this:

```
String str = null;

try {
    ...
    str = "condition2";
} catch (ApplicationException|IllegalStateException|Exception ex) {
    str = "condition3";
}
```

BTW: The code you've posted, as well as my Java 7 code could all be collapsed into simply `catch (Exception e)`, because [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) is a superclass of both [`ApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/portable/ApplicationException.html) and [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).

Comment: But isn't that pointless since the first two extend `Exception`? He should just catch `Exception` as long as he's doing that anyway.

Comment: I'm guessing he's not showing all the code there, so grouping them like this probably won't work.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Yes. But the same is true of the OP's equivalent Java 6 code. I'm just demonstrating the syntax. Nevertheless, I'll add a note about that.

Comment: Catch (ApplicationException|IllegalStateException|Exception) : is that necessary to keep Exception there........ as it is super class, i mean Exception alone is sufficient

Comment: They are subclasses but I want to print different message for each sub exception.

Comment: If you want to print a different message for each exception type, you need to do the three different blocks you posted in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 7 exception handling syntax. Java 7 supports multiple Exception handling in one catch block. Exp -

```
String str = null;

try{
  ...
  str = "condition2";
}catch (ApplicationException | IllegalStateException | Exception  ae) {
  str = "condition3";
}
```

Comment: I dont want grouping exception as each exception will have a seperate message etc

Comment: In this case you will have to follow traditional try catch block. try{
  ...
  str = "condition2";
}catch (ApplicationException ae) {
  str = "condition3";
}catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
  str = "condition3";
}catch (Exception e) {
  str = "condition3";
}

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
  ...
  str = "condition2";
}catch (Exception ae) {
 str = "condition3";
}
```

As all others are subclasses of **Exception**. If you want to show different messages, then can try as follow

```
try{
   ...
   str = "condition2";
}catch(ApplicationException | IllegalStateException e){
if(e instanceof ApplicationException)
    //your specfic message
    else if(e instanceof IllegalStateException)
    //your specific message
    else
        //your specific message
    str = "condition3";
}
```

Comment: yes they are subclasses but I want to print different message for each sub exception.

Answer (score 1):

You must add "final" keyword if you are using Java 7 feature of catching multiple exception in single catch block

```
catch (final ApplicationException|IllegalStateException|Exception ex) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing same thing in `ApplicationException` and `IllegalStateException` catch blocks and in general exception `Exception` catch block, then you can remove `ApplicationException` and `IllegalStateException` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and provide this:

```
String str = null;

 try{
     ...
     str = "condition2";
 }catch (Throwable e) {
    str = "condition3";
 }
 finally {
     if(str == null){
         str = "none";
     }
 }
```

If this is not what you mean by "sum up" then please clarify.

Please read

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: catchFinally will be a block that will execute only after catch statement(s).